# How to Create Unique Edit Fields for particular Item in React

Tags: reactjs

From the title itself. I am learning new in React and I have a problem with regards to the editing fields.

Whenever I click on a particular item to be edited, the rest of the items not selected will also be edited as shown in the screenshow below. I was wondering how can I generate unique edit field boxes that will only edit the particular field that is currently selected. Everytime I input a new item on the editedField I get this kind of bug.

[image]

Code

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

class Skills extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = { 
            skills : ["Frost Bolt", "Arcane Missle"],
            skillField : '',
            skiller : '',
            editIsHidden : true,
            editConfIsHidden : true,
            editSkillField : '',
        };

        // Event Listeners
        this.addSkill = this.addSkill.bind(this);
        this.removeSkill = this.removeSkill.bind(this);
        this.editSkill = this.editSkill.bind(this);
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
        this.clearField = this.clearField.bind(this);
        this.confirmEdit = this.confirmEdit.bind(this);
    }

    clearField() {
        this.setState({
            skillField : ''
        });
    }

    handleChange(event, element) {
        this.setState({
            [element] : event.target.value
        });
    }

    editSkill(editedSkill) {

        this.setState({
            editIsHidden : false
        });

        this.setState({
            editConfIsHidden : false
        });
    }

    confirmEdit(oldEditedSkill) {
        let index = 0;
        let skillsArray = this.state.skills;
        let newEditedSkill = this.state.editSkillField;

        this.state.skills.forEach(function(skill) {
            if (skill == oldEditedSkill) {
                skillsArray[index] = newEditedSkill;
                console.log(newEditedSkill);
            }
            index++;
        });

        this.setState({
            skills : skillsArray
        });

        this.setState({
            editConfIsHidden : true
        });

        this.setState({
            editIsHidden : true
        });

        console.log(this.state.skills);
    }

    addSkill() {
        this.state.skills.push(this.state.skillField);
        this.setState({
            skills: this.state.skills
        });
        console.log(this.state.skills);
        this.clearField();
    }

    removeSkill(removedSkill) {
        let adr = 0;
        let skillsArray = this.state.skills;

        this.state.skills.forEach(function(skill) {
            if (skill == removedSkill) {
                skillsArray.splice(adr, 1); 
            }
            adr++;
        });

        this.setState({
            skills : skillsArray
        });
    }

    render() {
        const skillLists = this.state.skills.map((val) => {
            return  <li>{val}
                        <input onChange={(e) => this.handleChange(e, "editSkillField")} value={this.state.editSkillField} className={this.state.editIsHidden ? 'hidden' : ''} />
                        <button onClick={() => this.removeSkill(val)}>x</button>
                        <button onClick={() => this.editSkill(val)}>e</button>
                        <button onClick={() => this.confirmEdit(val)} className={this.state.editConfIsHidden ? 'hidden' : ''} >ok</button>
                    </li>
        });
        return (
            <div>
                <input onChange={(e) => this.handleChange(e, "skillField")} value={this.state.skillField} />
                <button onClick={this.addSkill}>Add Skill</button>
                <h4>Skills</h4>
                <ul>{skillLists}</ul>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Skills;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you closely look at the code where `skills` are mapped, one could find that the className `hidden` is enabled or disabled for every item in the list as in the below code.

```
<input onChange={(e) => this.handleChange(e, "editSkillField")} value= {this.state.editSkillField} className={this.state.editIsHidden ? 'hidden' : ''} />
```

We need to first have a state that tells the particular field in question is editable. You can get this done in a number of ways based on your requirement. Here is one way to do it.

Your `editSkill` function has to store the `skill` that is to be edited. Something below would work.

```
editSkill(editedSkill) {
 this.setState({
  editIsHidden : editedSkill
 });

 this.setState({
  editConfIsHidden : editedSkill
 });
}
```

Then, your render would modify a little as shown below

```
const skillLists = this.state.skills.map((val) => {
 return  <li>{val}
          <input onChange={(e) => this.handleChange(e, "editSkillField")} value={this.state.editSkillField} className={(this.state.editIsHidden !== val) ? 'hidden' : ''} />
          <button onClick={() => this.removeSkill(val)}>x</button>
          <button onClick={() => this.editSkill(val)}>e</button>
          <button onClick={() => this.confirmEdit(val)} className={(this.state.editConfIsHidden !== val) ? 'hidden' : ''} >ok</button>
         </li>
});
```

Then in your `confirmEdit` function, reset the values of the respective state variables like

```
 this.setState({
  editConfIsHidden : null,
 });

 this.setState({
  editIsHidden : null,
 });
```

That would help your solution. However, there are few things one should take into consideration.

1. Try to maintain less number of states. I hope the states `editConfIsHidden` and `editIsHidden` could be replaced with one single state, unless you have specific use cases to use them separately.
2. When we are trying to set the state, we can make use of a single call to `this.setState` instead of sequential and multiple `setState` as show in this answer.

Comment: Thank you! I'll take note of your suggestions!  It worked by the way! exactly what I needed

Answer (score 0):

You should consider changing it to object like this this way you can handle it easily and you do not have to maintain other properties.

```
skills: [{ id: "Frost Bolt", value: '' }, { id: "Arcane Missle", value: '' }],
```

when input changes try changing like this

```
  handleChangeSkills(event, element) {
    this.setState({
      skills: this.state.skills.map(a => {
        if (a.id === element) {
          a.value = event.target.Value;
        }
        return a;
      })
    });
  }
```

leave your handlechange as it is

```
  handleChange(event, element) {
    this.setState({
      [element]:event.target.value
    });
  }
```

and call it in skills inputs like this

```
 <input onChange={(e) => this.handleChangeSkills(e, val.id)} 
value={val.val} className={this.state.editIsHidden ? 'hidden' : ''} />
```

Here is the [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-el1pi4)